# Ruby 2.2.2 extracted but not installed?

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I read that the Software Center doesn't always have the latest version of Ruby, so I went ahead and downloaded it from the Ruby website. The problem is, I'm new to Linux so I don't know if it's installed, or where the program file (executable?) is located. What should I do?

I'm going to guess that it's not a good idea to install things to a live USB...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you downloaded the source code, (if you didn't please do) run the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/where/you/downloaded/ruby
tar -zxf ruby-2.2.2.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.2.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And you should have ruby installed!

Comment: Where do I find the terminal? (I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu.)

Comment: @JorinGedamke: Ctrl+Alt+T, or open the dash and type "Terminal".

Comment: And if you downloaded it to the normal location, the path is probably `~/Downloads`.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I shouldn't unpack the archive to my desktop. Otherwise the terminal just blinks and says, "There is no such directory."

Comment: @CollDude you probably meant `tar -zxf`, otherwise it will only extract a non-gzipped tar file.

Comment: It's still playing Archimedes. There is, too, such a directory.

Comment: @JorinGedamke Please tell us where you downloaded the Ruby archive and which command have you used for it to return this error.

Comment: It's in "Downloads". I tried using cd /home/downloads and cd downloads with the same result.

Comment: @JorinGedamke That's because Downloads isn't in /home, but in /home/yourusername, `cd ~/Downloads` will work. Note that you can list the directory you are in with `ls` to figure out where your files are. I just wonder if you really need to compile Ruby from sources if you can't use the command line.

Comment: I apologize for this answer. Looking back, I see this was a bad answer (but also a bad question). Please disregard. I would delete but it is accepted.